# Incompatibility backgrounds css in IOS Mobile

Tags: html, ios, css

i developer a web site and when i open in IOS (Chrome or Safari) the resolution the background imgs break... TKS

CSS

```
 #home {
background: url('../images/fundo3.jpg') 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;*
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
color: #5C5C5C;
display: -webkit-box
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-box-align: center;
-webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
       align-items: center;
height: 100vh;
text-align: center;}


.parallax-section {
background-attachment: scroll !important;
background-size: cover !important;}


footer {
background: url('../images/footer-bg.jpg')  fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
color: #ffffff;
padding-top: 80px;
padding-bottom: 80px;}
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZVoD.jpg desktop
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5HWP.jpg ios

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create some mobile or iOS specific media queries and tweak the background image pixel size until you get a satisfactory size. Remember, you need high resolution graphics in order to get a nice result on newer iOS devices.

Code to tweak the size:
Replace

```
background-size: cover !important;}
```

With

```
background-size: 1500px,contain;
```